# Why does array.filter() return an array without whitespace?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently working on programming challenge from codecamp.com, and I getting the right numbers in my array; however, there is no white space so the site does not recognize it.

This is my code:

```js
function uniteUnique(arr) {
  arr = [];
  var returnArr;
  var storeArr = [];
  var temp = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
    temp = arguments[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < temp.length; j++){
      arr.push(temp[j]);
    }
  }

  function filter (value) {
    if (storeArr.indexOf(value) == -1){
      storeArr.push(value);
    }
    return value;
  }

  arr = arr.filter(filter);
  return storeArr;
}

uniteUnique([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1], [6, 7, 8]);
```

the output is [1,2,3,5,4,6,7,8]

the desired output is [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8]

Comment: Where do you print/output the array?

Comment: Your array with no spaces or with 100 spaces is still same array. As cramopy told - how do you print it?

Comment: the output is [1,2,3,5,4,6,7,8] , the desired output is [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8] can you explain please ?

Comment: the output is not handled by me, but the free code camp website. The return value of the function is essentially the output. Does that answer your question?

Comment: the output and desired output are different because the desired output contains white space.

Answer (score 0):

As long as all the elements in the array are correct, the whitespace between them doesn't matter.

Seems to be an error with Freecodecamp in that case, are you sure this is the output you're supposed to be getting? If so, I'd advice opening a support ticket or form another communication link with the Freecodecamp tutors.

Comment: Thanks that was what I thought. I have checked to make sure the elements are correct in multiple ways, and they are.